# Wide range of opinions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There is a question, *"[Using C/Pthreads: do shared variables need to be volatile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78172/using-c-pthreads-do-shared-variables-need-to-be-volatile)"*, with a broad range of answers that are conflicting, mutually exclusive or just plain wrong.

I have a comment to make that might clarify the situation, but the machinery says I don't have 50 points. It there a way to make an exception?

Comment: If you wan to include the comment here I can post it for you.  If you get it up to answer quality you could post a answer and work on getting that 50 rep so you can comment.

Comment: I'm amazed such a broad question has remained open TBH

Comment: why SHOULD we make an exception? Everyone thinks "but I need to comment!".... truly, you don't....  Get the 50 rep, it's easy, and then comment :).

Comment: find the relative chat room and ask someone else to make the comment perhaps?

Answer (score 10):

> Any way to make an exception?

No, go answer some other questions and get some reputation. 4 upvotes shouldn't take you too long.

When you've done that the question will still be there for you to comment on. Given that it's been around since '08, it's not going anywhere.

Comment: *it's not going anywhere* it might fall victim to the meta-effect ...

Comment: @rene, sure, so someone else with rep might chime in first, or take the appropriate action. It's just a catalyst. In the end the question will still be there (even if it's closed).

Answer (score 1):

If you think you have a better understanding of the question than what is shown in the existing answers, you can add a new answer and explain your insight there (while actually answering the question, of course).

As far as comments are concerned, it shouldn't take you very long to get 50 reputation. The fastest way to earn it is by answering questions, but if you'd rather not earn it that way, you can earn it by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Based on the content of this question, it should be easy for you to find posts whose spelling and grammar could be improved. Just be sure to make edits that significantly improve the posts, as people rightly disapprove of users suggesting trivial edits to gain reputation.